# powerbi - embedded how to give access to power bi embedded?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I work from a Colombian company that has the subcription to azure and we also are Microsoft partner Gold. I have a question which is this. my company has an administrator account with azure and I would like to give access to Power BI Embedded to a one of our developers but I don't know how. the administrator account belongs to @hotmail.com account and my employee has the @visiontecnologica.com account, so How can I give access to power Bi Embedded to him?

Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about simply adding this user to your Active Directory? Permissions to PowerBi Embedded should be managed the same way access to your native app are.

Answer (score 0):

Add the user to your Active Directory.
Alternatively, you can setup a new fictitious developer user for him\her and give them the credentials for it.